# ANDROID - Activity does not destroy the main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a main Activity takes a while to load, as it reads the customer base and load screen. When I call another Activity (which shows outstanding customer receipts), to give the "back" button I load the main Activity instantly. However when I call the other Activitys (Orders, History, etc. ..), to give the "back" button takes a while to show again Customers. It's like one of the Activity does not destroy the main Activity, and the rest if you destroy it. All are created in the same way (I think). Can this happen? What to call an Activity is not destroyed the main? Can be a memory issue?

Comment: Try posting your sources. As a hint - if you want to destroy Activity - call finish();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, when going from one `Activity` to the other, the first `Activity` is not destroyed.  It's pushed on to a backstack so that you can immediately go back to it when the user presses "back".

Its contents *can* however be destroyed if the current top `Activity` takes up too much memory.  The Android OS will free up the resources from the activities in the back stack in order to accommodate the needs of the foreground activity.  In this event, the activity will effectively be "restarted" and must be rebuilt when the user presses "back".

Comment: You can tell Android that does not destroy an Activity never given? (With a FLAG or something)

Comment: There's no flag that I'm aware of.  You have to assume that it *can* be destroyed at any time and be prepared to rebuild if it has been.  This usually involves an if-statement in `onCreate` or `onResume` that's something like `if(objectNotFound){// recreate the object}`.